# "taste for" vs. "taste in"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

What is the correct usage of 'taste for' and 'taste in'?

> 1. You have a good *taste for* music
> 2. You have a good *taste in* music.
> 3. Your *taste for* books is pathetic

Answer (score 2):

You would always say 'taste in' something. The only time I can think of where 'taste for' might be appropriate is if you are talking about having a craving for a certain food:

```
"I really have a taste for chicken tonight."
```

Comment: I think it can be used more broadly than that: *He has a taste for high adventure.*  *He has a taste for symphony music.*  *He had a taste for reading.*

Answer (score 2):

[*Taste for*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/taste+for) means a liking for or predilection for something. *A taste for beer* means a liking for beer, not necessarily any knowledge of beer.

*[Taste in (meaning 3 here)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taste)* means the ability to distinguish the good from bad in some area of knowledge. *Good taste in beer* means the ability to tell good beer from bad.

Of your example sentences, the second is correct, as they all deal with discernment, and so *taste in* should be preferred.